# Custom language highlighting to existing language?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I am working in a language called Sedona on windows that is very similar to C#, and was wondering if there was any way to highlight my .sedona documents like they were in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:set syntax=languageName` to force vim to use that kind of highlighting. So you would use `:set syntax=cs` to force C# highlighting.

Then you could put the following in your vimrc to use the C# syntax for .sedona files:

```
"Force vim to use C# syntax highlighting for all files with .sedona
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.sedona :set syntax=cs
```

Or you could put the following in your vimrc to use the C# filetype (everything that C# gets) for .sedona files:

```
"Associate all sedona files with the C# filetype
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.sedona setfiletype cs
```

Comment: If there's indeed high similarity, setting the filetype is recommended; this sets the syntax automatically, too.

Comment: Would I put those lines just anywhere in the _vimrc file? Or would I modify the cs.vim file?

Comment: Nevermind, I put it in the middle of a function like an idiot. Thanks!